# UITableViewCell outside TableView Bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, addsubview

How can I add a view to `UITableViewCell` outside of `UITableView` bounds?
On iOS6, the blue view appears but when scroll it disappears. On iOS7, the blue view doesn't appear at all. Any help. Thanks.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITableView *aTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    aTableView.dataSource = self;
    aTableView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:aTableView];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44);

    UIView *redView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)];
    redView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIView *blueView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 44)];
    blueView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 100);

    [cell.contentView addSubview:redView];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:blueView];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`tableView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;`?